# Object Detection in openCV

Tags: visual-c++, opencv

I have a problem with my program written in Visual C++ using OpenCV:
i have to capture frames from webcam and find all the various rectangle (it doesn't matter the color). 
I try to modify the samples in c, squares.c, but it doesn't work as well, because the program wait any key (different from 'q') to continue.

This is the code. Someone can tell me where is the problem???
Thank you in advance.

```
//
// Object Detection of squares
// Take images from webcam and find the square in them
// 
//
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int thresh = 50;
IplImage* img = 0;
IplImage* img0 = 0;
CvMemStorage* storage = 0;
//const char* wndname = "Square Detection Demo with Webcam";

// helper function:
// finds a cosine of angle between vectors
// from pt0->pt1 and from pt0->pt2 
double angle( CvPoint* pt1, CvPoint* pt2, CvPoint* pt0 )
{
    double dx1 = pt1->x - pt0->x;
    double dy1 = pt1->y - pt0->y;
    double dx2 = pt2->x - pt0->x;
    double dy2 = pt2->y - pt0->y;
    return (dx1*dx2 + dy1*dy2)/sqrt((dx1*dx1 + dy1*dy1)*(dx2*dx2 + dy2*dy2) + 1e-10);
}

// returns sequence of squares detected on the image.
// the sequence is stored in the specified memory storage
CvSeq* findSquares4( IplImage* img, CvMemStorage* storage )
{
    CvSeq* contours;
    int i, c, l, N = 11;
    CvSize sz = cvSize( img->width & -2, img->height & -2 );
    IplImage* timg = cvCloneImage( img ); // make a copy of input image
    IplImage* gray = cvCreateImage( sz, 8, 1 ); 
    IplImage* pyr = cvCreateImage( cvSize(sz.width/2, sz.height/2), 8, 3 );
    IplImage* tgray;
    CvSeq* result;
    double s, t;
    // create empty sequence that will contain points -
    // 4 points per square (the square's vertices)
    CvSeq* squares = cvCreateSeq( 0, sizeof(CvSeq), sizeof(CvPoint), storage );

    // select the maximum ROI in the image
    // with the width and height divisible by 2
    cvSetImageROI( timg, cvRect( 0, 0, sz.width, sz.height ));

    // down-scale and upscale the image to filter out the noise
    cvPyrDown( timg, pyr, 7 );
    cvPyrUp( pyr, timg, 7 );
    tgray = cvCreateImage( sz, 8, 1 );

    // find squares in every color plane of the image
    for( c = 0; c < 3; c++ )
    {
        // extract the c-th color plane
        cvSetImageCOI( timg, c+1 );
        cvCopy( timg, tgray, 0 );

        // try several threshold levels
        for( l = 0; l < N; l++ )
        {
            // hack: use Canny instead of zero threshold level.
            // Canny helps to catch squares with gradient shading 
            if( l == 0 )
            {
                // apply Canny. Take the upper threshold from slider
                // and set the lower to 0 (which forces edges merging) 
                cvCanny( tgray, gray, 0, thresh, 5 );
                // dilate canny output to remove potential
                // holes between edge segments 
                cvDilate( gray, gray, 0, 1 );
            }
            else
            {
                // apply threshold if l!=0:
                //     tgray(x,y) = gray(x,y) < (l+1)*255/N ? 255 : 0
                cvThreshold( tgray, gray, (l+1)*255/N, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY );
            }

            // find contours and store them all as a list
            cvFindContours( gray, storage, &contours, sizeof(CvContour),
                CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0,0) );

            // test each contour
            while( contours )
            {
                // approximate contour with accuracy proportional
                // to the contour perimeter
                result = cvApproxPoly( contours, sizeof(CvContour), storage,
                    CV_POLY_APPROX_DP, cvContourPerimeter(contours)*0.02, 0 );
                // square contours should have 4 vertices after approximation
                // relatively large area (to filter out noisy contours)
                // and be convex.
                // Note: absolute value of an area is used because
                // area may be positive or negative - in accordance with the
                // contour orientation
                if( result->total == 4 &&
                    fabs(cvContourArea(result,CV_WHOLE_SEQ)) > 1000 &&
                    cvCheckContourConvexity(result) )
                {
                    s = 0;
                    printf("ciclo for annidato fino a 5\t\n");
                    for( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
                    {
                        // find minimum angle between joint
                        // edges (maximum of cosine)
                        if( i >= 2 )
                        {
                            t = fabs(angle(
                            (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem( result, i ),
                            (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem( result, i-2 ),
                            (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem( result, i-1 )));
                            s = s > t ? s : t;
                        }
                    }

                    // if cosines of all angles are small
                    // (all angles are ~90 degree) then write quandrange
                    // vertices to resultant sequence 
                    if( s < 0.3 )
                        for( i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
                            cvSeqPush( squares,
                                (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem( result, i ));
                }

                // take the next contour
                contours = contours->h_next;
            }
        }
    }

    // release all the temporary images
    cvReleaseImage( &gray );
    cvReleaseImage( &pyr );
    cvReleaseImage( &tgray );
    cvReleaseImage( &timg );

    return squares;
}


// the function draws all the squares in the image
void drawSquares( IplImage* img, CvSeq* squares )
{
    CvSeqReader reader;
    IplImage* cpy = cvCloneImage( img );
    int i;

    // initialize reader of the sequence
    cvStartReadSeq( squares, &reader, 0 );

    // read 4 sequence elements at a time (all vertices of a square)
    for( i = 0; i < squares->total; i += 4 )
    {
        CvPoint pt[4], *rect = pt;
        int count = 4;

        // read 4 vertices
        CV_READ_SEQ_ELEM( pt[0], reader );
        CV_READ_SEQ_ELEM( pt[1], reader );
        CV_READ_SEQ_ELEM( pt[2], reader );
        CV_READ_SEQ_ELEM( pt[3], reader );

        // draw the square as a closed polyline 
        cvPolyLine( cpy, &rect, &count, 1, 1, CV_RGB(0,255,0), 3, CV_AA, 0 );
    }
 cvSaveImage("squares.jpg",cpy);

    //show the resultant image
    //cvShowImage( wndname, cpy );
    cvReleaseImage( &cpy );
 //return cpy;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 int key = 0;
 IplImage* frame =0;
 IplImage* squares=0;
    // create memory storage that will contain all the dynamic data
    storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

 CvCapture *camera = cvCreateCameraCapture(CV_CAP_ANY); /* Usa USB camera */

 frame = cvQueryFrame(camera);
 frame = cvQueryFrame(camera);
 frame = cvQueryFrame(camera);

 while(key!='q'){

  frame = cvQueryFrame(camera);
  frame = cvQueryFrame(camera);

  if(frame!=NULL){
   printf("Got frame\t\n");

   cvSaveImage("frame.jpg", frame);

   /*img0*/ img = cvLoadImage("frame.jpg");

   //img = cvCloneImage( img0 );

   cvNamedWindow( "img0", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

   cvShowImage("img0",/*img0*/img);

   // find and draw the squares 

   drawSquares( img, findSquares4( img, storage ) );

   squares = cvLoadImage("squares.jpg");

   // create window and a trackbar (slider) 
                       //with parent "image" and set callback
   //(the slider regulates upper threshold, 
                       //passed to Canny edge detector)
   cvNamedWindow( "main", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
   cvShowImage("main", squares);

   /* wait for key.
    Also the function cvWaitKey takes care of event processing */
   key = cvWaitKey(0);

  }
 }

        // release both images
        cvReleaseImage( &img );
        cvReleaseImage( &img0 );
  cvReleaseCapture(&camera);
  cvDestroyWindow("main");
  cvDestroyWindow("img0");
        // clear memory storage - reset free space position
        cvClearMemStorage( storage );

  return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The title of the question suggests you have an OpenCV problem, but then you say something about hitting the `q` key? Please isolate the precise problem, reducing your code to the smallest sample that still shows the problem. Then make clear what you see happen, and what you expected.

Comment: You can check this link on stackoverflow. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217519/opencv-cvwaitkey

Answer (score 3):

I believe your problem is here:

```
   /* wait for key.
    Also the function cvWaitKey takes care of event processing */
   key = cvWaitKey(0);
```

Try changing 0 to 10.

I see some other problems in your code. For instance, you create windows inside the while loop, which is not good. Try moving cvNamedWindow() function calls outside your while loop. Also, I'm not sure why you query camera for frames and do not process them?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i find the error. It was the function cvLoadImage(), because the programm try to load an image which it doesn't exist when i run for the first time the programm. So work with frame without save and load, the programm works.. ^^

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that the window dissappers without waiting for any hit from the keyboard, you can add a cvWaitKey(0) at the end of the code.

Also a getch( ) at the end would help. make sure you include  in the headers.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped.
I explain the problem better:
the program work, but it stops after the loading of the image, which was saved first int the function findSquares4() and it doesn't continue because it waits a key.
I can't find the error.
Can someone tell me why it waits a key??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i find the error.
It was the function cvLoadImage(), because the programm try to load an image which it doesn't exist when i run for the first time the programm.
So work with frame without save and load, the programm works.. ^^