# What does OpenCV's cvWaitKey( ) function do?

Tags: c++, c, opencv

What happens during the execution of `cvWaitKey()`? What are some typical use cases? I saw it in *OpenCV* reference but the documentation isn't clear on its exact purpose.

Comment: @user588855 It's important to all of us that you review your questions and accept some answers, including this.

Comment: For the record, `cvWaitKey()` is now a deprecated C function. `waitKey()` is the modern C++ equivalent.

Comment: Can you please mark one of the answers (@SuperElectric 's seems the best for now) so that the question can be considered answered. 4 years of waiting for an answer and getting multiple answers is a long period of time...

Comment: @DanielSloof for instance, it would be nice to know which standard do the return values follow.

Answer (score 158):

`cvWaitKey(x) / cv::waitKey(x)` does two things:

1. It waits for **x** milliseconds for a key press on a OpenCV window (i.e. created from `cv::imshow()`). Note that it does not listen on stdin for console input. If a key was pressed during that time, it returns the key's ASCII code. Otherwise, it returns `-1`. (If `x <= 0`, it waits indefinitely for the key press.)
2. It handles any windowing events, such as creating windows with `cv::namedWindow()`, or showing images with `cv::imshow()`.

A common mistake for opencv newcomers is to call `cv::imshow()` in a loop through video frames, without following up each draw with `cv::waitKey(30)`. In this case, nothing appears on screen, because highgui is never given time to process the draw requests from `cv::imshow()`.

Comment: For the future readers: Note that `cv2.waitKey(x)` or `cv::waitKey(x)` waits for a key event infinitely not only if *`x = 0`* but also if *`x < 0`* i.e. **`x <= 0`**. Source: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5628525ad33f52eab17feebcfba38bd7

Answer (score 25):

Plain simply, `cvWaitKey()` sleeps for **X** miliseconds, waiting for any key to be pressed.

```
int cvWaitKey(int X);
```

If a key is pressed, this function returns the ASCII code of key. Or returns **-1** if no keys were pressed during that time.

Comment: That's not quite the whole story. In practice, even if you don't care about keyboard input, calling this function can be essential to some OpenCV applications. There's some [more information here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/documentation/c/highgui/WaitKey).

Comment: @DrewNoakes the link you have shared is broken. If possible, could you please take a look and update it? Thank you!

Comment: Here is the URL via the wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20120122022754/http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/documentation/c/highgui/WaitKey

Comment: `cvWaitKey()` doesn't sleep for X miliseconds ... Where does X come from? And then there's no such a function! Most probably you mean **`cv.WaitKey(X)`**. Because `cv.WaitKey()` waits for a key to be pressed. Yet, you got upvotes for this wrong answer. (Well, it's not the first time ...)

Answer (score 14):

`cvWaitKey(0)` stops your program until you press a button.

`cvWaitKey(10)` doesn't stop your program but wake up and alert to end your program when you press a button. Its used into loops because `cvWaitkey` doesn't stop loop.

Normal use

```
char k;

k=cvWaitKey(0);

if(k == 'ESC')
```

with `k` you can see what key was pressed.

Comment: Also slightly more importantly - it's the openCV message loop. You won't see any new data in a cvNamedWindow unless you call cvWaitKey() in the loop

Comment: -1 from me for doing a comparison **char ?= multichar**. This is just wrong. Use either the printable character (which in this case is not possible since ESC is a non-printable character but in case for example of using the Q key you can do a ?= 'q' comparison) or pick one of the numerical representations. The ASCII supports multiple numerical systems: hexadecimal (0x1b), decimal (27) and octal (033). All listed represent the ESC key.

Comment: should be int not char, then use bit ops

Comment: @Vlad Yes, it should be 27 as in user1564486

Answer (score 9):

. argument of `0` is interpreted as `infinite`

. in order to drag the highGUI windows, you need to continually call the `cv::waitKey()` function. eg for static images:

`cv::imshow("winname", img);`

`while(cv::waitKey(1) != 27); // 27 = ascii value of ESC`

Answer (score 8):

Note for anybody who may have had problems with the `cvWaitKey( )` function. If you are finding that `cvWaitKey(x)` is not waiting at all, make sure you actually have a window open (i.e. `cvNamedWindow(...)`). Put the `cvNamedWindow(...)` declaration BEFORE any `cvWaitKey()` function calls.

Comment: Welcome on SO, it is a good place to post information like you did. Usually, when you post an answer it must bring new informations to the question, so it doesn't creates redundant post. Which was the case for your post. If you have smaller comment, you could also comment on the question later on (when you get more Rep). If you haven't read it yet, I suggest you to have a look to the FAQ : http://stackoverflow.com/faq. Regards

Answer (score 5):

```
/* Assuming this is a while loop -> e.g. video stream where img is obtained from say web camera.*/    
cvShowImage("Window",img);

/* A small interval of 10 milliseconds. This may be necessary to display the image correctly */
cvWaitKey(10);  

/* to wait until user feeds keyboard input replace with cvWaitKey(0); */
```

Answer (score 5):

The `cvWaitKey` simply provides something of a delay. For example:

```
char c = cvWaitKey(33);
if( c == 27 ) break;
```

Tis was apart of my code in which a video was loaded into openCV and the frames outputted. The `33` number in the code means that after `33ms`, a new frame would be shown. Hence, the was a dely or time interval of `33ms` between each frame being shown on the screen.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

`cvWaitKey(milliseconds)` simply wait for milliseconds provided as a parameter for a next key stroke of keyboard.

Human eyes not able to see the thing moving in less than 1/10 second, so we use this to hold same image frame for some time on screen. As soon as the key of keyboard is pressed the next operation will be perform.

In short `cvWaitKey(milliseconds)` wait either for key press or `millisecond` time provided.

Comment: "Human eyes not able to see the thing moving in less than 1/10 second, so we use this to hold same image frame for some time on screen. As soon as the key of keyboard is pressed the next operation will be perform" does this really matter to the question?

Answer (score 0):

waits milliseconds to check if the key is pressed, if pressed in that interval return its ascii value, otherwise it still -1