# How to check if an opencv window is closed

Tags: c++, c, opencv

How do you check if an opencv window has been closed?

I would like to do:

```
cvNamedWindow("main", 1);

while(!cvWindowIsClosed("main"))
{
    cvShowImage("main", myImage);   
}
```

but these is no such cvWindowIsClosed(...) function!

Comment: Never needed something like that in years. What are you trying to do, exactly? Most probably there's some other way to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: @karlphillip I'm looking to render new frames until the user closes the window.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are trying to do can be achieved with [`cvGetWindowHandle()`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/user_interface.html#getwindowhandle):

> The function cvGetWindowHandle returns the native window handle (HWND in case of Win32 and GtkWidget in case of GTK+). [Qt Backend Only] qt-specific details: The function cvGetWindowHandle returns the native window handle inheriting from the Qt class QWidget.

The idea is to get the handle of the window and then use specific platform API functions to check if that handle is still valid.

**EDIT:**

Or you could use the tradicional [`cvWaitKey()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5493668/176769) approach:

```
char exit_key_press = 0;
while (exit_key_press != 'q') // or key != ESC
{
   // retrieve frame

   // display frame

   exit_key_press = cvWaitKey(10);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have only one image window open, then clicking the 'x' button at its corner causes the waitkey() function to return a -1 value.
Then check if the cvGetWindowHandle("name_of_the_window") function returns 0 or not. If it does return 0, then the window is actually closed.
I have tested it in OpenCV3.
But I am still not very clear on the reason why the waitkey() return -. I will much appreciate if anyone explains why this happens.
[I don't know if my answer to this question will be relevant or not after such a long time. But hopefully if anyone else gets stuck with the same issue (like me), this answer might help them out.]
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the cv::getWindowProperty method.

Do like that:

```
cv::namedWindow("main", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

while(1)
{
     cv::imshow("main", myImage);

     // add this IF.
     if (cv::getWindowProperty("main", WND_PROP_AUTOSIZE) == -1)
         break;
}
```

When the windows be closed the getWindowProperty will return -1.

Answer (score 2):

This should do

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

std::string mTitle = "title of my window";

while (cvGetWindowHandle(mTitle.c_str()))
{
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python OpenCV version 3.4.2, Ubuntu Bionic, `cv2.getWindowProperty('Main', cv2.WND_PROP_VISIBLE)` returns a floating 0.0 (zero) when the window is closed and 1.0 (one) when it's open, whether see-able or not. Yes, still a 1.0 when it's minimized or behind another window or on a different desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Just before the end of the main(), put the following code:

```
int main(int, char**){
.
.
.

bool visible = true;
while(visible){
        waitKey(1000);
        visible = getWindowProperty("Main",WND_PROP_VISIBLE) > 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```