# how to not show image if the window is close?

Tags: opencv

I thought imshow not supposed to show image if the window don't exist but apparently it is. I don't understand if it is a bug of i did not understand correctly.

I am tring to not open a new window if the user close it. I thought I will open the window at init and at other part I just use imshow and that way if the user close the window it won't appear again. but because imshow show the image this is not working. how can i achieve this goal?

Comment: This concerns your OS environment. Try to handle the "close window event". E.g. use [cvGetWindowHandle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321389/how-to-check-if-an-opencv-window-is-closed).

Answer (score 0):

**When called, `cv::imshow()` will display the image on a window**. If that window doesn't exist at the time of the call, one will be created.

If you don't want to display a window, don't call `cv::imshow()`.