# how to get value from trackbar

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

i use Opencv and Python and i try to create an trackbar for the thresholding
now i want when i close the Window of trackbar the function return to me the value of min threshold or the binary image because i'll use this image in contour detection 
but i don't want to use this method (when i push the button ESC like:`ch = cv2.waitKey(27)
      if ch == 27 or ch == 0x10001b:
         break`
i want sut push the red button of exit this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnPY1.png)
my code :

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import cv2

 # cv2.threshold(src, thresh, maxval, type[, dst])

Image = cv2.imread("114.png")
cv2.namedWindow("Main", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow("Main", Image)


# Extraction of Blue channel
b = Image[:,:,0]
cv2.namedWindow("Only Blue Channel", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow("Only Blue Channel", b)

# Callback Function for Trackbar (but do not any work)
def nothing(*arg):
    pass

 # Generate trackbar Window Name
TrackbarName = "Trackbar"

 # Make Window and Trackbar
cv2.namedWindow("window", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.createTrackbar(TrackbarName, "window", 0, 250, nothing)

img_threshed = np.zeros(b.shape, np.uint8)

while True:
  # Get kernel size in trackbar
  TrackbarPos = cv2.getTrackbarPos(TrackbarName, "window")
  # Apply dilation
  limit = TrackbarPos
  ret,img_threshed = cv2.threshold(b,limit,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
  # Show in window
  cv2.imshow("window", img_threshed)

# Expanding borders of the objects
  kernel = np.ones((9, 9),np.uint8)
  img_dilated = cv2.dilate(img_threshed, kernel)
  cv2.namedWindow("Dilated Blue Channel", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
  cv2.imshow("Dilated Blue Channel", img_dilated)


# Retrieving contours by subtraction base objects from the expanded objects
  img_contours = img_dilated - img_threshed
  cv2.namedWindow("Contours", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
  cv2.imshow("Contours", img_contours)


cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Could you clarify your initial description of what you actually need? The code is simple and easy to read, but not the problem. I have added a solution per to my current understanding, but if I have understood question incorrectly, lemme know.

Comment: @saurabheights i want to get the value of thresholding then i will use this image in detection of contour

Comment: Yes, I can see that from reading the code. Please read your question(not the code part, but the initial problem). Write it in proper English, it's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: like this it's okey ?

Comment: I think it's more interpretable. I think you want to close the trackbar window and store the result in a variable to process after your while loop. But what is the issue with using the escape key? Note that, waitKey is more of a helper function to allow GUI to respond and thus is needed. And storing threshold value is simple, just read the Trackbar position after while loop ends and before destroyAllWindows.

Comment: If you still want to detect whether the window is closed, try this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35003476/opencv-python-how-to-detect-if-a-window-is-closed, but I don't see the hate towards escape key, poor she/he.

Comment: thanks @saurabheights that what i need ^^