# Why does the OpenCV loop not end

Tags: python

i have a simple webcam opening using cv2 module:

```
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('webcam',img)
    k=cv2.waitKey(10)
    if k == 27:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyWindows()
```

this program runs for ever, although i try to close it, the only way is closing vsCode

Comment: `k == 27`, that means Esc is the way to break out from OpenCV's loop. Go to the window displaying the webcam feed and press the Escape Key.

Comment: cv2 window doesn't stop your loop when you close window using button `[X]`. You have to use key `ESC` to stop loop and then it will close window too. I some question I saw some function to check if window is visible to stop loop when you use button `[X]` but this not popular so I don't remember code.

Comment: did you try to use `Ctrl+C` in terminal/console to stop code? Normally it works. `VS Code` should have also button to stop executing code - so it shouldn't need to close all `VS Code`

Comment: [OpenCV Python: How to detect if a window is closed? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35003476/opencv-python-how-to-detect-if-a-window-is-closed)

Answer (score -1):

You can close the webcam window by clicking on your webcam window and press `esc` while if you want to close it with specific alphabet then you can use the below code to destroy the window by pressing `q`.

```
import cv2
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('webcam',img)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break        
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```