# OpenCv: Application hangs when rotating an image in a for loop

Tags: .net, image, opencv, image-processing

The following code gives seg fault  and some time stalls/hangs and never works.

```
for(i=0;i<360;i++)

{

CVrotate(image, i); //i is angle


display("image" in some window);  

}
```

but the following work very well.

```
 for(i=0;i<360;i++)

 {

 CVrotate(image, i); //i is angle

 waitkey(10);

 display("image" in some window);  
 }
```

Cvrotate is a function that is rotating an image, and the rotated image is being displayed by the opencv function for displaying.

Why is waitkey(); needed here? 
I understand that the display should be called only after CVrotate is done with its job. Similarly, I am assuming that the next iteration starts when the display is over and not before that. Please enlighten me.

Comment: If every thing is given in tutorial probably SO would not have come into existence!! I just read the SO FAQ, did not find any place where it says "I can not ask about 10 questions in last two days on Opencv"

Comment: Before asking a question you have to find (Google) similar questions to yours and understand the problem you faced. After this you have to fix/find solution by yourself. But you're just blindly asking a questions. I alerady give you a pointer to the answer - did you find a solution?

Comment: Oh Yes, your answer was helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[What does OpenCV's cvWaitKey( ) function do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217519/opencv-cvwaitkey)  this link clears all the misconceptions regarding the cvWaitkey and its uses .Hope this is useful for you. cvWaitKey's main function is to pause the code for a while.

Comment: Reading the original specification Doc did not help me. but this one is now clear to me. Thanks