# what does waitKey (30) mean in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OpenCV - cvWaitKey( )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217519/opencv-cvwaitkey)

I want to filter the video frame.

```
for(;;)
{
cap.read( frame);
medianBlur(frame,framedst,5);
imshow("frame",frame);
imshow("framedst",framedst);    
if( waitKey (30) >= 0) break;
}
```

What does the `waitKey(30)` mean? Because if I comment out the line `if( waitKey (30) >= 0) break;`, the above code doesn't work!

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217519/opencv-cvwaitkey) asks about `waitkey`, and I believe the answer explains why your `imshow` doesn't work. Quoting the answer, *A common mistake for opencv newcomers is to call cv::imshow() in a loop through video frames, without following up each draw with cv::waitKey(30). In this case, nothing appears on screen, because highgui is never given time to process the draw requests from cv::imshow().*

Comment: That's right ,I don't use OPENCV much

Comment: @chris when I use a webcam as input, I do not have to call waitKey. But surely the system could be confused a bit about displaying too much in too little time.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The function `waitKey()` waits for a key event for a "delay" (here, 30 milliseconds). As explained in the [OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=waitkey#waitkey), HighGui (`imshow()` is a function of HighGui) need a call of waitKey regularly, in order to process its event loop.

Ie, if you don't call waitKey, HighGui cannot process windows events like redraw, resizing, input event, etc. So just call it, even with a 1ms delay :)

Comment: then that mean cWaitkey () does not have any relation to capture image after 30 milliseconds. It has to wait and display image on display window.

Comment: With `waitKey` I find the assumption that it will return -1 after timeout on Windows is sometimes wrong - instead it returns 255. and so many common codes exit their main loop almost immediately. It seems the solution to this cross-platform issue is to use `waitKeyEx` instead.