# Imshow from opencv is not working anymore

Tags: c++, opencv

I wrote some simple programs using imshow function. It worked fine few times. I've tried to view two pictures, before and after processing. For the first time it worked fine, but the second time it crashed my application.

Now imshow crash application every time.

How to fix that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat image, gray_image;
    string file_path;

    cout << "Input file path: ";
    cin >> file_path;

    image = imread(file_path, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
    if (image.data==NULL)
        {
            cout << "No image found!";
            return 1;
        }

    cvtColor(image, gray_image, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    namedWindow("Orig", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    namedWindow("Gray", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    imshow("Orig", image);
    imshow("Gray", gray_image);

    cout << "Output file path: ";
    cin >> file_path;

    imwrite(file_path, gray_image);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should probably show us some code and what exactly you changed.

Comment: Stack trace would be useful too.

Comment: I didn't changed anything, just ran the same program second time.

Comment: What error messages do you get?

Comment: Please change your question to state instead: "How do I debug an application crash?"  And then we could all answer some generic methods useful for investigating a crash.  In the absence of such a change, I'm inclined to vote for closure.  Even with the change it might be closed as an exact duplicate.

Comment: If you're getting a segfault, try putting some more `cout`'s in at various places (particularly between the 2 calls to `imshow` as I have a feeling it's the second one that might through a segfault). Let us know where it crashes, what kind of crash and if applicable copy in the stack trace.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need [waitKey](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#waitkey)

See [what does waitKey (30) mean in OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452118/what-does-waitkey-30-mean-in-opencv)

Comment: I know, but with and without waitKey imshow windows are shown, with correct size, but filled with gray colour. It is possible to enter path to output file in console and program returns 0, but if you try interact with imshow windows it crashes.

Comment: @mitu imshow() filled with grey means it hasn't been updated with data - the image isn't drawn until the waitkey() call