# C++ waitKey Delay to Display Images in Loop

Tags: c++, image, loops, opencv

Within C++ (also using OpenCV) I'm creating a loop which displays a new image from file each iteration. To achieve this I've had to add in `waitKey(1)` otherwise only a blank window is displayed. I was just wondering why this millisecond delay must be included for the image to show each iteration and, if possible, if there is a method to display the image without requiring this delay.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if performance relevant, care that waitKey(1) doesnt mean it will wait 1ms, but AT LEAST 1ms... On windows it will typically wait a minimum of 5-15ms afair. If necessary you should code your own displaying with OpenGl, Qt or something. OpenCV GUI is more about a fast coded gui for debugging and simple visualization, typically not for commercial code.

Comment: Ideally I'd prefer to remove this delay entirely, so I will have to look into this method using OpenGL or the like. Thanks for the heads up on that one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The function waitKey() waits for key event for a "delay" (here, 30
>   milliseconds). As explained in the OpenCV documentation, HighGui
>   (imshow() is a function of HighGui) need a call of waitKey reguraly,
>   in order to process its event loop.
>
> Ie, if you don't call waitKey, HighGui cannot process windows events
>   like redraw, resizing, input event etc. So just call it, even with a
>   1ms delay :)

[what does waitKey (30) mean in OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452118/what-does-waitkey-30-mean-in-opencv)

Comment: Ahh that makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much!