# openCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4)

Tags: c, opencv, video-capture

I am having Assertion failed error at the last frame , while reading and writing a video frame by frame. The errors only shows at the last frame, don't know why. saw this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15972059/assertion-failed-in-unknown-function), whichs suggests to give waitkey, my code already have wait key on it.

my simple code is as follows

```
int main()
{
  CvCapture *capture=cvCaptureFromFile("C:\\vid\\op.mp4");
  if(capture==NULL)
   {
 printf("can't open video");
   }
   Mat frame, first_frame,current_frame;
  char buffer[100];
  int frame_count=1,p=1;
  while(1)
   {
   /*Getting the current frame from the video*/
    frame=cvQueryFrame(capture);
    cv::cvtColor(frame,current_frame,1);   //saving current frame 
    sprintf(buffer,"C:\\frames\\image%u.jpg",p);    
    imwrite(buffer,current_frame);
    p++;

     waitKey(1);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Anybody please help

Solution: I added a check just after reading every file as-

```
if(frame.empty()){
    fprinf("cannot access frame");
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to check your frame is empty or not after each query

Like

```
   frame=cvQueryFrame(capture);
     if (frame.empty()) break;
```

You are getting such an error because you are trying to convert an empty Mat to grayscale after last frame, so exit the loop if frame is empty.

Comment: You can also get this error if you load an image as gray scale, than attempt to cvtColor with something like BGR2XXXX

Comment: @Haris I have a similar problem that I have asked about in a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45534183/opencv-error-assertion-failed-on-ios?noredirect=1#comment78053692_45534183 I would really appreciate it if you could take a look at it.