# creating a grayscale video using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, camera

I need to save a grayscale video from a GIge camera using `OpenCV` on Mac os X 10.8. I used this code:

```
 namedWindow("My video",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
 Size frameSize(659, 493);
 VideoWriter oVideoWriter ("MyVideo.avi",-1, 30, frameSize, false);

 While(1)
 {
 ...
     Mat Image=Mat(Size(GCamera.Frames[Index].Width,GCamera.Frames[Index].Height),CV_8UC1,GCamera.Frames[Index].ImageBuffer);

     oVideoWriter.write(Image);
 ...   
 }
```

I got this error:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, file /Users/rosa/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 3270
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
>   The program has unexpectedly finished.

Comment: Maybe your frame is empty. Please check this post [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871540/opencv-error-assertion-failed-scn-3-scn-4). He got the same error.

Comment: @Constantine, No because I show and save frames on hard disk and it is correct.

Comment: @Constantine, In my code i did not use cvtColor anywhere because the acquired frame is originally grayscale. I remark that the error is in this line oVideoWriter.write(Image);

Answer (score 3):

I made it this way:

```
 VideoWriter oVideoWriter ("MyVideo.avi",CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'), 30, frameSize);

 While(1)
 {
     Mat Image=Mat(Size(GCamera.Frames[Index].Width,GCamera.Frames[Index].Height),CV_8UC1,GCamera.Frames[Index].ImageBuffer);
     Mat colorFrame;
     cvtColor(Image, colorFrame, CV_GRAY2BGR);
     oVideoWriter.write(colorFrame);
 }
```

Comment: the error is disappeared but the video does not work and it has a fixed size 414 bytes

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is your operating system. Checking the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videowriter), it says the greyscale feature is supported on Windows only.

Easy enough fix though,

```
cv::Mat imageGrey;
cv::Mat imageArr[] = {Image, Image, Image};
cv::merge(imageArr, 3, imageGrey);

oVideoWriter.write(imageGrey);
```

Comment: the error is disappeared but the video does not work and it has a fixed size 414 bytes

Comment: Again, operating system. You can only use the -1 flag in the video writer constructor on windows. Otherwise you need CV_FOURCC(...), I'd check the doc. and make sure you have it all right: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videowriter

Comment: I have used CV_FOURCC('8','B','P','S') and it is working now!