# Capture image from webcam and display it - OpenCV - Eclipse - Windows

Tags: c, opencv, frame, webcam, video-capture

I'm new to OpenCV and I want to display what my webcam sees with OpenCV. I'm using the C Coding Language.

I've tried with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <cv.h> // Include the OpenCV library
#include <highgui.h> // Include interfaces for video capturing

int main()
{
    cvNamedWindow("Window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    CvCapture* capture =cvCreateCameraCapture(-1);
    if (!capture){
        printf("Error. Cannot capture.");
    }
    else{
        cvNamedWindow("Window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

        while (1){
            IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
            if(!frame){
                printf("Error. Cannot get the frame.");
                break;
            }
        cvShowImage("Window",frame);
        }
        cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
        cvDestroyWindow("Window");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My webcam's light turns on, but the result is a completely grey window, with no image.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add

```
cvWaitKey(30);
```

to the end of `while`-loop.

---

`cvWaitKey(x) / cv::waitKey(x)` does two things:

1. It waits for **x** milliseconds for a key press. If a key was pressed during that time, it returns the key's ASCII code. Otherwise, it returns `-1`.
2. It handles any windowing events, such as creating windows with `cvNamedWindow()`, or showing images with `cvShowImage()`.

A common mistake for opencv newcomers is to call `cvShowImage()` in a loop through video frames, without following up each draw with `cvWaitKey(30)`. In this case, nothing appears on screen, because highgui is never given time to process the draw requests from `cvShowImage()`.

See [What does OpenCV's cvWaitKey( ) function do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217519/opencv-cvwaitkey) for more info.