# OpenCV animation

Tags: c++, opencv

I am making Langton's Ant in C++, when I try to draw squares, I can. But I can't make this in loop.

```
for(int i = 0;i<=100;i++){
        rectangle( image, Point( i*5, 0 ), Point( (i*5)+5, 5), Scalar( 0, 55, 255 ), CV_FILLED, 4 );
        imshow("kare",image);
        Sleep(100);
    }
```

It waits for 10 seconds, then draw all the squares same time. If I add `cvWaitKey(0);` before sleep, I get same problem. When I "touch" the key, it draw, but when I hold, it doesn't draw. When I back off my finger, it draw.

How can I solve it?
Regards.

Comment: Please post the whole source code. `Sleep` can be pretty much anything, as you don't show us your includes. It's a rather common name (and not part of the obvious candidate OpenCV). Why you'd call `cvWaitKey` (or `waitKey`) before doing a Sleep also seems redundant, so what the function does or where it comes from is even more unclear...

Answer (score 6):

You are mixing C and C++ API, `cvWaitKey(0)` belongs to deprecated C. Also  `cvWaitKey(0)`  waits until user press key.

So just use

`waitKey(33)` instead of `sleep()`, which will wait 33 ms after each `imshow()`.

Comment: Thanks. But why Sleep makes problem?

Comment: Sleep doesn’t work for imshow(), you should use waitKey() for HighGui operation like imshow(). Also these links http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#waitkey http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217519/opencv-cvwaitkey

Comment: How can I make it faster? When I write `waitKey(10)`, I can't get 100 square in second. Is there any way?

Comment: Use minimum delay, but  the speed depends on precessing time between two imshow(). Also the Docs says, since the OS has a minimum time between switching threads, the function will not wait exactly delay ms, it will wait at least delay ms, depending on what else is running on your computer at that time.